# Accessing bound context in user controls code behind

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, code-behind, custom-object

Question is much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654493/passing-custom-objects-to-usercontrol-via-xaml-binding)- just didn't pan out for me

**So how do I access a Property on a WPF usercontrol bound via Parent's Xaml in, from the Controls Code behind?**

**PS:** Other controls bound to Properties of the TowerBase model passed in are binding. ( I just can't access the model passed in in the code behind ).

**UserControl:** x and y are null and I can't figure out why

```
public partial class TowerControl : UserControl
{
    public TowerBase model = new TowerBase(); //Trying to set this model

    public TowerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var x = ((TowerBase)this.DataContext); //Or Extract from binding
        var y = model;
    }
    ...
```

**From the parent's xaml:**

```
    ...
    <controls:TowerControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Tower" DataContext="{Binding Tower}" />
    ...
```

**Parent Model:**

```
    ...
    public TowerBase Tower { get; set; }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `UserControl's` `DataContext` would not be set by the time it is in constructor. Listen to `Loaded` event of user control and in handler you will get the `DataContext`

```
<UserControl Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = this.DataContext;
}
```