# Passing custom objects to UserControl with XAML binding

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to bind a custom object to a usercontrol via XAML :

I have a MainPage and a user control. The model object :

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        TestToto = new Test() { Id = 1, Value = "A value" };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Test _test;
    public Test TestToto
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TestToto"); }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and the user control :

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Debug.WriteLine($"ID =====================> {PropertyTest}");
    }

    public Test PropertyTest
    {
        get { return (Test)GetValue(PropertyTestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyTestProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PropertyTest.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyTestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyTest", typeof(Test), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(Test)));

}
```

In my MainPage.xaml, i create an instance of MyUserControl1 by binding dependencyproperty PropertyTest to TestToto (see MainPage.xaml.cs) :

```
<Grid>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding TestToto.Value}" />

    <local:MyUserControl1 Grid.Row="2"
                          PropertyTest="{Binding DataContext.TestToto, ElementName=maPage}" />
</Grid>
```

Here maPage is the name of MainPage page. Then in my user control's XAML i have :

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="30,47,0,0"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding PropertyTest.Value}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="146" />
</Grid>
```

The problem is that PropertyTest DP is always null :

[image]

First TextBox display Value property from MainPage and second Textbox should diplay the same.

For information, i follow [this post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654493/passing-custom-objects-to-usercontrol-via-xaml-binding).

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: You aren't creating an instance of MainPageViewModel and assigning it to MainPage's DataContext, or maybe you just omitted that?

Comment: Oh ****, thansk you, let me explain : in my main page'xaml i have an instance og MainPageViewModel BUT set in Grid like this : <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MainPageViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>

But in my usercontrol in indicated that DataContext was in MainPage scope (and no in Grid scope), so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thansk to Decade Moon, i found the problem :

in my Main Page, i declared DataContext in the main Grid like this :

```
<Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>
```

But when i bind property to usercontrol DP i indicated that DataContext was in Main Page (maPage) scope like this :

```
PropertyTest="{Binding DataContext.TestToto, ElementName=maPage}"
```

So i just changed scope of my DataContext to Page :

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now it works.